# Error 400 when uploading a Google appengine application

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I keep getting the following message when trying to deploy the sample application from within Eclipse. I tried to post an image of my Application settings but being a newbie it wouldn't let me.

------------ Deploying frontend ------------
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=http%3A%2F%2Fgdbguesttest.appspot.com%2F&version=1&
400 Bad Request

Here is a copy and paste from the application settings:
Application Identifier Alias:
gdbguesttest.appspot.com
Between 6 and 30 characters. Provides an alternative URL to access your application through appspot.com. It can be used to enable Channel, XMPP, Email, and SSL access for your application.
http://gdbguesttest.appspot.com
Datastore Replication Options:
High Replication
Uses a highly replicated Datastore that synchronously replicates data across multiple locations simultaneously.

Comment: I did see the other post about this but I did put the application id in the correct place in the appengine-web.xml file as instructed.

Comment: Make sure you are logged in with Correct Email on eclipse, and put the APP ID only under properties > google app engine > project id 'gdbguesttest'. It is not at all necessary in web.xml file.

Comment: Thanks Ankur, I did realize the id only and posted an answer to my own question but I couldn't until after 8 hours (answer my own question that is.)  But thank you for taking the time to read and answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK found my problem.  You only should put your app ID, not the entire path.

So in my case.

gdbguesttest

NOT

http://gdbguesttest.appspot.com